# Ranking using dates

Tags: mysql

So, I have this table:

```
promo_id      transac_id        date
--------      ----------        ----

 656265         213516       05/21/2016
 656265         213520       05/21/2016
 656265         213521       05/21/2016
 656265         213530       05/22/2016
 656265         213540       05/25/2016
 895134         365124       06/01/2016
 895134         365130       06/03/2016
 895134         365135       06/04/2016
```

How could I rank the `transac_id` based on the `date` with the same `promo_id`?
This is what I would like to see:

```
promo_id      transac_id        date        rank
--------      ----------        ----        ----

 656265         213516       05/21/2016       1
 656265         213520       05/21/2016       2
 656265         213521       05/21/2016       3
 656265         213530       05/22/2016       4
 656265         213540       05/25/2016       5
 895134         365124       06/01/2016       1
 895134         365130       06/03/2016       2
 895134         365135       06/04/2016       3
```

Comment: what is with the last date?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Typo error :)

Answer (score 0):

schema:

```
create table t1
(   id int not null,
    thedate date not null
);
insert t1 (id,thedate) values (1,'2017-01-02'),(2,'2016-01-02'),(3,'2018-01-02');
```

query:

```
SELECT id,thedate,@rn:=@rn+1 as rank
FROM t1
cross join (select @rn:=0) xParams 
ORDER BY thedate;

+----+------------+------+
| id | thedate    | rank |
+----+------------+------+
|  2 | 2016-01-02 |    1 |
|  1 | 2017-01-02 |    2 |
|  3 | 2018-01-02 |    3 |
+----+------------+------+
```

`xParams` is a derived table name. Every derived table needs a name. It is for a `cross join` to initialize the variable (@rn) for ranking.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I actually need another column where their rank is.

Comment: SQ Fiddle based on @Bruce Davin Wilner's answer [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bcca)